# How to change color theme and font size of jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter, mvcjqgrid, jqgrid-inlinenav

I have created application in MVC 4, jquery and jqgrid.

I have used jqgrid in one of page as below:

```
          $('#g).jqGrid({
            ajaxGridOptions: {
                error: function () {
                    $('#g')[0].grid.hDiv.loading = false;
                    alert('An error has occurred.');
                }
            },
            url: '@Url.Action("Getvalues", "cntrollName")/' + 0,
            postData: { ID: rowID },
            datatype: 'json',
            jsonReader: { root: 'List', page: 'Page', total: 'TotalPages', records: 'TotalCount', repeatitems: false, id: 'ID' },
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['GrdID', Name],
            colModel: [
                { name: ID, index: ID, hidden: true },
                { name: 'FullName', index: 'FullName', width: 150 }
                                ],
            pager: $('#g),
            sortname: ID,
            rowNum: 10,
            width: '525',
            height: '100%',
            viewrecords: true,
            beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
                                   return true;
            },
            sortorder: 'desc'
        }).navGrid('#g, { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false });
```

Please share me how **i could change color and font size of jqgrid.**

For now, it just shows default light blue theme and its default font size.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

jqGrid are based on jQuery UI Theme. To change colors you can either download the theme (see [here](http://jqueryui.com/download/) and choose the theme at the dropdown at the bottom of the page) or customize your own theme [here](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/). In the way you can easy change all colors.

To change the font size you will have to overwrite some CSS styles defined in `ui.jqgrid.css`. Just search for `font-size` and `height` with pixel values. If you will need to increase the font size you will need to increase some `height` values of grid's parts.